# How to iterate through regex matching groups

Tags: regex, go

say my data looks like this:

```
name=peter 
age=40
id=99
```

I can create a regex

```
(\w+)=(\w+)
```

To match name, age, and id into group1, and peter, 40, 99 into group two. However, I want to iterate and even selectively iterate through these groups. E.g.,

I want to do different processing if the group1 value is id. So the algorithm is like

```
//iterate through all the group1, if I see group1 value is "id", then I assign the corresponding group2 key to some other variable. E.g., newVar = 99
```

The second thing I want to do is to just jump to the third instance of the matching group1 and get the key "id" out instead of iterating.

Comment: Just match what you want to change Find `(id1|id2|id3)=(\w+)` replace $1=<replace>` or simply `id=\w+` If available, you could use a callback to determine what group1 matched, then replace accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [FindAllStringSubmatch](https://godoc.org/regexp#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch) to find all the matches:

```
pat := regexp.MustCompile(`(\w+)=(\w+)`)
matches := pat.FindAllStringSubmatch(data, -1) // matches is [][]string
```

Iterate through the matched groups like this:

```
for _, match := range matches {
    fmt.Printf("key=%s, value=%s\n", match[1], match[2])
}
```

Check for "id" by comparing with match[1]:

```
for _, match := range matches {
    if match[1] == "id" {
        fmt.Println("the id is: ", match[2])
    }
}
```

Get the third match by indexing:

```
match := matches[2] // third match
fmt.Printf("key=%s, value=%s\n", match[1], match[2])
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/fUOHkYpm_A)